# Serialize checkbox array, also get checkboxes with off-value

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox, serialization

I was wondering if this is possible.
The serialize-string will be inserted in a mySQL-database, so it would be fine if all checkboxes would be inserted and not only the ones that is ticked(on).

it's possible to make on column in the database for each of the checkboxes, and use this if/else-statement:

```
if(isset($_GET['checkbox'])) {
                  // It's checked!
         }
         else {
                  // not checked!
         }
```

but its a bit unappropriate...

Comment: Your statement "the serialize string will be inserted in a mySQL database" is concerning.  You don't mean you're going to have a varchar or text column that simply stores the serialized string, right?  Each checkbox will really be its own independent column, right?

Comment: hum. that's what I meant, actually. that the serialized string will be stored in a varchar-column.
is it better if I have one column for each checkbox..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Give all the checkboxes the **same** name (ending in `[]` since this is PHP)
2. Give all the checkboxes different **values**
3. Have an array of all possible values in the script (you can use the same array when generating the HTML for the form!)
4. Loop over it and use [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to determine if you should set it to true or false
5. Pass the result to your database function